# VB.Net how to change variable based on counter

Tags: vb.net

I have a For Next Loop that will connect to a database, then search through the results and assign the results to a variable.  Right now I'm displaying it in the form of a message box.  I'd like that variable to change with the counter

My program:

```
For x = 1 to 5

            dtstartdate = dtpStartDate.Value
            dtenddate = dtpEndDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)


            Try
                connetionString = "Data Source=..."
                sql = "Select * discounts"
                connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
                connection.Open()
                command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                adapter.SelectCommand = command
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 130
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtstartdate)
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtenddate)
                adapter.Fill(ds)
                connection.Close()
                connection.Dispose()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)

        For Each Result As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Select Case Result("Report")
                Case "TOTALS"
                    Select Case Result("Description")
                        Case "Coupons", "Coupons Tax-Free", "GC"
                            sum = sum + (Result("netAmt"))
                    End Select

            End Select
        Next
```

Next

How would I assign "SUM" to change for each loop through.  For example:

If x is 1 i'd like "Sum" to be "Sum1":

```
For Each Result As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Select Case Result("Report")
                    Case "TOTALS"
                        Select Case Result("Description")
                            Case "Coupons", "Coupons Tax-Free", "GC"
                                sum1 = sum1 + (Result("netAmt"))
                        End Select

                End Select
```

If x is 2 I'd like sum to be sum2

```
For Each Result As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Select Case Result("Report")
                    Case "TOTALS"
                        Select Case Result("Description")
                            Case "Coupons", "Coupons Tax-Free", "GC"
                                sum2 = sum2 + (Result("netAmt"))
                        End Select

                End Select
```

SO on and so forth.  At the end of the program, I'll be displaying "Sum1", "Sum2", "Sum3" on a report.

Comment: Use a single variable representing an Array, a List, or [another appropriate collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx). Code that uses variables a1,a2,..aN is almost always written incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array for your sum variable. Instead of changing the name of the variable (sum1, sum2, sum3) you would just have to change the index of the array ( sum(1), sum(2), sum(3)... which would look like sum(x) ) and store your values in those indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would change is your query.
If I am not mistaken you are interested only in the rows where the `Report` field contains the word `'TOTALS'` and the `Description` field contains the words `'Coupons' or 'Coupons Tax-Free' or 'GC'`.

So you could change your query to express a WHERE condition.
This will dramatically reduce the rows returned and the complexity of the final totals.
(By the way, are you sure that you don't need to increment also the @startDate parameter?)

Second thing is the use of a List(Of Double) instead of a single variable

```
Dim sumTotals = new List(Of Double)()
For x = 1 to 5
   ....
   sql = "Select * discounts WHERE Report = 'TOTALS' " & _ 
                             "AND Description IN('Coupons', 'Coupons Tax-Free, 'GC'"
   ....

   Dim partialSum As Double
   For Each Result In ds.Tables(0).Rows
       partialSum = partialSum + (Result("netAmt"))
   Next
   sumTotals.Add(partialSum)
Next
```

Now, at the end of the For Loop you have a List of 5 double values (one for each day) that you can use as a normal array

```
For each x in sumTotals
   Console.WriteLine(x)
Next
....
```

Or apply a Linq extension

```
Dim grandTotal = sumTotals.Sum()
```

Comment: I'm not interested in changing the query.  I'll ultimately use a stored procedure to pull the reports and cherry pick the items i'm looking for from the resulting query.  I'd rather do it through vb, than make 10 different database queries from VB.